# Question on Quotient Rings and moding

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Hi guys just a quick question If we have an integral domain and we mod it with an irreducible element such as

$K[x,y,z]/<p(x,y,z)>$ where p is irreducible polynomial then the resulting polynomial ring has only constant polynomials as units.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is from what you wrote. Care to clarify?

Comment: Sure my motivation was $R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ where R is the real numbers and I wanted to argue that the only units are the constant polynomials

Comment: It is best not to call the elements of such a quotient ring «polynomials». Mostly, because they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the quotient $K[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

Comment: Okay, here we have that xy is a unit, but in the other ring we have $x^2+y^2=1$ where we cannot factor the $x^2+y^2$ over the real numbers

Comment: Well, xy is just equal to 1 in my ring, so that its being a unit is not very interesting: you should look of other units...

Comment: I am answering the question you asked. If you wanted to ask something else, you should add it to the question.